# Ruby Reg Ex Identify Pipe Within Quotes

Tags: ruby, regex

I want a regex to identify pipe characters within double quotes.

I was using

```
\".+\|.+\"
```

which correctly matches on '1|Some "quote | text"|4' 
and correctly does not match on '1|Some "quoted" text|4'

However, it also matches on '1|Some "quoted" text|4|5|6|More "quoted" text|9'
because there are 2 sets of quotes - it sees the outer-most quotes and the pipes between.

How do I change the regex to not match in that case?

UPDATE: Turns out I need it to match on multiple pipes within quotes.  I had been using:

```
/\"([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\"/
```

which works for 1 pipe within the quotes, such as "1|Some "quote | text"|4", but now I need it to also match on something like "1|Some "quote | text | with | pipes"|4".

Any ideas???

Comment: Can your quotes be delimited as well? For example: `"A \"quoted\" string"`

Comment: I'll bet you're dealing with pipe-delimited csv. Ruby has a CSV class for that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.+` which matches any character, you want to match any character except `|`. To do that you want `[^|]+`. Based on what you have written, that should be what you want.

Comment: Not even close. This won't recognize if the `|` is inside or outside of the quotes.

Comment: The idea was to replace his calls of `.+` with `[^|]+`. I think that is clear from the answer. The rest of his regex is fine.

Comment: No it's not because it doesn't recognize if it's inside or outside of double quotes.